# empheq amsart enumerate error

Tags: align, enumerate, amsart, empheq

I have started using the empheq package and run into some issues. The following compiles normally:

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand*\mybluebox[1]{\colorbox{blue!20}{\hspace{1em}#1\hspace{1em}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item We have
\begin{empheq}[box=\mybluebox]{equation}
f(x)=g(x)
\end{empheq}
\begin{empheq}[box=\mybluebox]{align}
f(x)=f(x)=g(x)
\end{empheq}
\item etc.
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

On the other hand, in the amsart class, there is a glitch with the align environment and empheq (which does not seem to appear with the equation environment), namely, replacing the class with

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{amsart}
```

messes up the empheq environment. Does anybody have an idea of how to fix it?
[image]

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  Did you try using `amsmath` and `align` with the `article` document class?  It would be well to determine whether the problem is with `amsart` or `amsmath`.  At the moment, this is apples vs. oranges.

Comment: There is also another interesting feature here: why is the box narrower when using `amsart` (compare the sizes without `fleqn` between `article` and `amsart`)

Comment: Best solution I can offer right now is `\renewcommand\fullwidthdisplay{}` plus `reqno` class option (as resetting that macro seems to move the `leqno` placings

Comment: I've added it as an issue to the new bug tracker: https://github.com/latex3/mathtools/issues/5 (it is shared with mathtools)

Comment: Hi thanks for taking some time to look at my question! I had indeed tried with article and amsmath, and everything worked well. It is the amsart class

Comment: Thank you for sharing my issue daleif. I specifically want leqno/fleqn however. Any trick appreciated!

Comment: Remember to use @name when you answer others, then the site informs them. Otherwise you have to wait until they come back (if they do).

Comment: I've also noted that it is only `align` that has issues, `equation`, `gather` even `alignat` seems fine

Comment: @daleif yes sorry ! Also, I hadn't noticed that alignat was working fine. I guess this is worth reporting the bug, but alignat provides a workaround for almost everything that align does. Thanks for noticing that!

Comment: This is now fixed in the next release. Including a bunch of other amsart related stuff in empheq.

Answer (score 1):

Not really an answer, but need more space

Update 2020/03/18: Updated fix. Though this does **not** work with the `flalign` env

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{amsart}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand*\mybluebox[1]{\colorbox{blue!20}{\hspace{1em}#1\hspace{1em}}}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\MHInternalSyntaxOn
\def\EQ_initialize:{%
  \m@th
  \MH_let:NwN\SetTagPlusEndMark\EQ_tag_plus_endmark:
  \MH_let:NwN\SetOnlyEndMark\EQ_only_endmark:
  \l_EQ_temp_linewidth_dim\linewidth
  \@tempdima\z@
  \begingroup
  \ifdefined\fullwidthdisplay\relax
    \fullwidthdisplay
    \global\@tempdima\displaywidth
  \fi
  \endgroup
  \ifdim\@tempdima>\linewidth\relax
    \l_EQ_temp_linewidth_dim\@tempdima
  \fi
  \@tempdima\z@
  \g_EQ_toprow_height_dim\z@
  \g_EQ_bottomrow_depth_dim\z@
  \g_EQ_toptag_height_dim\z@
  \g_EQ_bottomtag_depth_dim\z@
  \g_EQ_widesttag_dim\z@
  \xdef\g_EQ_latest_nonzerodepth_row_fint{\z@}
  \edef\EQ_restore_tex_delimiter:{%
    \delimiterfactor\the\delimiterfactor
    \delimitershortfall\the\delimitershortfall\relax}%
  \g@addto@macro\EQ_complete_mathdisplay:
                \EQ_restore_tex_delimiter:
  \delimitershortfall\EmphEqdelimitershortfall
  \delimiterfactor\EmphEqdelimiterfactor
  \MH_let:NwN\intertext@\EQ_intertext:
  \EQ_displaybreak:}


% trick to see what empheq is typesetting
%\def\EQ_use_mathdisplay:{%
%  \EQ_outerbox:{\fbox{\usebox{\EQ_mathdisplay_box}}}}

\MHInternalSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item We have
\begin{empheq}[box=\mybluebox]{equation}
f(x)=g(x)
\end{empheq}
\begin{empheq}[box=\mybluebox]{align}
f(x)=f(x)=g(x)
\end{empheq}
\item no empheq
  \begin{equation}
    f(x)=g(x)
  \end{equation}
  \begin{align}
    f(x)=f(x)=g(x)
\end{align}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks @daleif! If this is alright with you, although between this and the alignat workaround, I may leave the question open in case this leads to a bug fix? I am not 100% sure what the policy is on this.

Comment: @Math-user that is the intent. As mentioned this is just because of the limited space in the comments